# How do you handle favoriting many different models?

Tags: laravel

I need your advise how I can handle the function "favorting" better. Currently, I have these endpoints:

```
Route::post('/api/favorite/food/{food}', 'FavoriteController@store');
Route::delete('/api/favorite/food/{food}', 'FavoriteController@destroy');

Route::post('/api/favorite/profiletweet/{profiletweet}', 'FavoriteController@store');
Route::delete('/api/favorite/profiletweet/{profiletweet}', 'FavoriteController@destroy');
```

@store is for favoriting a model and @destroy is for unfavoriting.

```
public function store($model)
{
    $model->favorite();
}

public function destroy($model)
{
    $model->unfavorite();
}
```

So this worked very well but now I have got two new problems to handle:

1. I'm creating two additional models that are also able to be favorited. So it would be nice to have only two lines of Routes, not (2*n)
2. Before that food only used as a slug the id. Nos it uses the title as a slug. But my favorite-button-component just knows the class name and the id to construct the URL. I don't want to write if cases to set the URL right.

How are you handling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got my own anwser:

I used Laravel Route Explicit Binding.

In RouteServiceProvider:

```
Route::bind('favorite', function($value){
   if (request()->route()->hasParameter('type')){
        $class = 'App\\'.request()->type;
        $model = new $class();
        return $model->findOrFail($value);
   }
   abort(404);
});
```

In Web.php it's only:

```
Route::post('/api/favorite/{type}/{favorite}', 'FavoriteController@store');
Route::delete('/api/favorite/{type}/{favorite}', 'FavoriteController@destroy');
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a package - [Laravel Likeable Plugin](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-likeable)

Or if you want to build this functionality from scratch : [Tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/implement-a-favoriting-feature-using-laravel-and-vue-js)

You should also look into [Polymorphism](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

There's also a resource called [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/18). It has a lot of free content, but some require a membership.

Comment: Thank you anyways. I knew about nr.1, but wrote it after Laracast. Thanks for the Tutorial I learned something knew.